# Org-mode schedule 1 event for multiple days?

Tags: org-mode

I cannot find anything on being able to set `TODO` tasks with `SCHEDULE` to occur on multiple days of the week.

For example I have `STAT` class on `Mon` `Wed` and `Fri` that I would like the event to repeat every week with a `+1w` argument.

Is this possible or do I need to have 3 separate `STAT` events, each with a `1w` argument in `SCHEDULE`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that org-mode wants you to think of [meetings differently](http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html#index-org_002dscheduled_002ddelay_002ddays-871):

> Scheduling an item in Org mode should not be understood in the same
>   way that we understand scheduling a meeting. Setting a date for a
>   meeting is just a simple appointment, you should mark this entry with
>   a simple plain timestamp, to get this item shown on the date where it
>   applies. This is a frequent misunderstanding by Org users. In Org
>   mode, scheduling means setting a date when you want to start working
>   on an action item.

I guess part of the point is that it doesn't really make sense to mark meetings as DONE. But I'm not really sure.

Anyway, that just changes the question to "how do I specify in a 'simple plain timestamp' multiple recurring dates?"

We can use functions from the diary library, as such:

```
* 100% chance of statistics today
SCHEDULED: <%%(or (diary-cyclic 7 8 31 2015) (diary-cyclic 7 9 2 2015) (diary-cyclic 7 9 4 2015))>
```

Now it'll show up every Monday, Wednesday, and Friday starting 2015-08-31. You won't mark it as DONE; it'll just be "scheduled" for those days.

As mentioned in a comment, you can also just use regular timestamps with repeaters:

```
* 100% chance of statistics today
<2015-08-31 Mon +1w><2015-09-02 Wed +1w><2015-09-04 Fri +1w>
```

Note that if you just use `C-c .` twice, org mode will think you're doing a date range. This will also work :

```
* 100% chance of statistics today
SCHEDULED: <2015-08-31 Mon +1w>--<2015-09-02 Wed>
```

Comment: But in that case the `SCHEDULED` doesn't really get you anything and you could just add 3 plain timestamps: <2015-08-31 +1w> <2015-09-02 +1w> <2015-09-04 +1w>