# How to schedule todo in org for every even day, and similar for every odd day?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to schedule a todo item every Monday, Wednesday, Friday.

I followed this one:
[Org-mode schedule 1 event for multiple days?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16680/org-mode-schedule-1-event-for-multiple-days)

and get something like this:

```
* stuff to do
SCHEDULED: <Monday 4/5/2020 +1w><Wed 6/5/2020 +1w><Fri 8/5/2020 +1w>
```

This doesnt show up on my agenda.  So I think the way I write it down is wrong.  Could anyone give some pointers?

Comment: Not directly related to your question but `SCHEDULED` in Org mode means something different than e.g. scheduling a meeting. See the [discussion](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-Scheduling) in the manual, particularly the disclaimer marked `Important`. E.g. if you have a meeting at 11am every MWF, then you probably should not mark it `SCHEDULED`, you should just use a timestamp. It's not clear from your example whether you want/need `SCHEDULED` or not, so I thought I'd point that out.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to create a custom function that tests for specified days of the week.  The following example is hard-coded to return `t` for Monday (i.e., `1`), Wednesday (i.e., `3`) and Friday (i.e., `5`).

This can be used in an `org-mode` file such as:

```
* My Task
  SCHEDULED: <%%(diary-monday-wednesday-friday date)>
```

Or, it can be used in a `diary` file and seen in the agenda view with `(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)` using a diary entry such as:

```
%%(diary-monday-wednesday-friday date) Monday or Wednesday or Friday
```

**CODE**:

```lisp
(require 'calendar)

;;; ORG-MODE:  * My Task
;;;              SCHEDULED: <%%(diary-monday-wednesday-friday date)>
;;;
;;; DIARY:  %%(diary-monday-wednesday-friday date) Monday or Wednesday or Friday
;;;
;;; See also:  (setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
;;;
;;; (diary-monday-wednesday-friday '(5 7 2020)) => nil
;;;
;;; (diary-monday-wednesday-friday '(5 8 2020)) => t
;;;
;;; 0 => Sunday
;;; 1 => Monday
;;; 2 => Tuesday
;;; 3 => Wednesday
;;; 4 => Thursday
;;; 5 => Friday
;;; 6 => Saturday
;;;
(defun diary-monday-wednesday-friday (date)
"Return `t` if DATE is a Monday, Wednesday or Friday."
  (let ((day-of-week (calendar-day-of-week date)))
    (member day-of-week '(1 3 5))))
```

Comment: Such diary-style expressions are discussed in the Org mode manual: see [Timestamps](https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps) for the timestamp use and [Weekly/Daily Agenda](https://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html#Weekly_002fdaily-agenda) for the anniversary/birthday/etc use, which can be done even without including the diary.

Answer (score 1):

If this is really an appointment reminder, rather than a scheduled task, then the easiest thing to do is to forego the `SCHEDULED:` marker and just have the three timestamps listed (I like putting the timestamps on different lines, but you can put them on a single line if you want):

```
* stuff to do
  <Monday 4/5/2020 +1w>
  <Wed 6/5/2020 +1w>
  <Fri 8/5/2020 +1w>
```

Assuming that the file is indeed an agenda file, `stuff to do` will appear in the agenda every Monday, Wednesday and Friday.